# Apple Maps Doesn't Rotate

Tags: macos, maps

I just installed Mavericks, but when I open Maps, the two-finger rotate gesture does nothing. The gesture is active in System Preferences. The compass does not appear in Maps. I can use the same gesture in Preview. The pinch-to-zoom feature works fine. Is this a hardware issue or is there something I forgot to activate?

Comment: What view are you using? Satellite view or Flyover or any other?

Comment: It doesn't work for any view

Comment: I usually use Hybrid, but the point is that NO view works.

Comment: Can you rotate when holding down the alt key and moving with one finger?

Comment: No. I've been told previously that this was a bug and I should get an Apple Genius appointment, but I wanted to check if anyone else had a different answer.

Comment: So, what's the result?